# How to get values from shared preference and check it using if

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I'm using user login screen. In that I'm using shared preferences to store the user details and store whether the user is logged in or not. I'm using splash screen and in that splash activity I checked a value from sharedpreference to know whether the user is already logged in or not.If the user logged in,then after splash it will go to dashboard otherwise it goes to login screen.But i am getting null pointer error.please help me.

**My shared prefrence class is:**

```
public class Userloginsession {

    public static final String IS_User_login = "isuserloggedin";
    //    {"did":"1","drivername":"arul ji","dusername":"PIKDRIVER01","logid":"79"}
    //Driver Login details
    //From DRIVER
    public static final String IS_SNO = "sno";
    public static final String IS_USERNAME = "userloginname";
    public static final String IS_USERPASSWORD = "userloginpassword";
    //
    public static final String IS_EMP_ID = "emp_id";
    //
    //From Json Driver
    public static final String IS_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
    public static final String IS_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
    public static final String IS_IMAGE = "image";

     static SharedPreferences user_details;
    // Editor Reference for sharedpref
    SharedPreferences.Editor user_details_editor;

    public Userloginsession(final Context applicationContext) {

        // create sharedpreff file "driverSession" for DRIVERLOGINACTIVITY
        user_details = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("usersession",0);

        //Edit pfeff file
        user_details_editor = user_details.edit();
        user_details_editor.apply();


    }
    public static boolean isuserLoggedIn() {
        return user_details.getBoolean(IS_User_login, false);
    }
    public void createuserLogin(String passwordp, String username, String SNO, final String EMP_ID, final String FIRST_NAME, final String LAST_NAME, final String Image) {
        user_details_editor.putBoolean(IS_User_login, true);
        user_details_editor.putString(IS_USERNAME, username);
        user_details_editor.putString(IS_USERPASSWORD, passwordp);
        user_details_editor.putString(IS_SNO, SNO);
        user_details_editor.putString(IS_EMP_ID, EMP_ID);
        user_details_editor.putString(IS_FIRST_NAME, FIRST_NAME);
        user_details_editor.putString(IS_LAST_NAME, LAST_NAME);
        user_details_editor.putString(IS_IMAGE, Image);
        user_details_editor.commit();
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> isGetuserDetails() {
        // Use hashmap to store user credentials
        final HashMap<String, String> userdetailsmap = new HashMap<>();

        // Driv pass
        userdetailsmap.put(IS_USERNAME, user_details.getString(IS_USERNAME, null));   // Driv Pass

        // Driver user name
        userdetailsmap.put(IS_USERPASSWORD, user_details.getString(IS_USERPASSWORD, null));

        // Driver  ID
        userdetailsmap.put(IS_SNO, user_details.getString(IS_SNO, null));

        //Driver Name
        userdetailsmap.put(IS_EMP_ID, user_details.getString(IS_EMP_ID, null));
        userdetailsmap.put(IS_FIRST_NAME, user_details.getString(IS_FIRST_NAME, null));
        userdetailsmap.put(IS_LAST_NAME, user_details.getString(IS_LAST_NAME, null));
        userdetailsmap.put(IS_IMAGE, user_details.getString(IS_IMAGE, null));

        return userdetailsmap;
    }

    public void clearAllvalues() {

        user_details_editor = user_details.edit();
        user_details_editor.clear();
        user_details_editor.apply();

    }


}
```

**My splashscreen acticty is :**

```
public class Splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen2);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity

                    if (Userloginsession.isuserLoggedIn()) {
//                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RideHistry.class));
                        startActivity(new Intent(Splashscreen.this, Dashboard.class));
                    /*overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);*/
                        finish();


                    } else {
                        //   if driver not login go to DriverLogin Activity
                        startActivity(new Intent(Splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class));

                        finish();
                    }
                /*} else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class));

                    finish();
                }*/
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

**My error is:**

```
        Process: com.example.notebook.dptextiles, PID: 214    java.lang.NullPointerException:
    Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.content.SharedPreferences.getBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference 
    at com.example.notebook.dptextiles.fragments.Userloginsession.isuserLoggedIn(Userloginsession.java:45 
    at com.example.notebook.dptextiles.Splashscreen$1.run(Splashscreen at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Userloginsession.isuserLoggedIn()` directly
use it like this

```
Userloginsession login=new Userloginsession(getApplicationContext());
if (login.isuserLoggedIn())
```

The problem is your are not initializing the sharedpreference. Ie. Userloginsession not get initialized. For that you need to give activity **context**.

the overall class should be

```
public class Splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen2);
        Userloginsession login=new Userloginsession(getApplicationContext());
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity

                    if (login.isuserLoggedIn()) {
//                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RideHistry.class));
                        startActivity(new Intent(Splashscreen.this, Dashboard.class));
                    /*overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);*/
                        finish();


                    } else {
                        //   if driver not login go to DriverLogin Activity
                        startActivity(new Intent(Splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class));

                        finish();
                    }
                /*} else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class));

                    finish();
                }*/
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sry..i am new to this..i upvoted bt dnt knw this mark..now i marked it

Comment: @lucky its ok now. always marking answer will get others happy, who has same issues..:)

Comment: @lucky Oh god see my answer see this line pref= new PrefManager(this); in your case   Userloginsession login=new Userloginsession(this);

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your shared preferences is initialised before query. Put a breakpoint and debug.

Answer (score 2):

you `user_details` shared preference is null..

in your Splash Activity:

initialize it like:

```
Userloginsession session = new Userloginsession(Splashscreen.this);
if (session.isuserLoggedIn()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a seperate Preference class

PrefManager.java

```
package name;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Ravi on 08/07/15.
 */
public class PrefManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "MegaInfomatix";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String KEY_IS_WAITING_FOR_SMS = "IsWaitingForSms";
    private static final String KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobile_number";
    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN = "isLoggedIn";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";

    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setIsWaitingForSms(boolean isWaiting) {
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_WAITING_FOR_SMS, isWaiting);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isWaitingForSms() {
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_WAITING_FOR_SMS, false);
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        editor.putString(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, mobileNumber);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return pref.getString(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, null);
    }

    public void createLogin(String name, String email, String mobile) {
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        editor.putString(KEY_MOBILE, mobile);
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
    }

    public void clearSession() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> profile = new HashMap<>();
        profile.put("name", pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
        profile.put("email", pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));
        profile.put("mobile", pref.getString(KEY_MOBILE, null));
        return profile;
    }
}
```

do this in LoginActivity class and in onCreate method
before onCreate method create preference class object

```
Preference pref;
pref = new PrefManager(this);

if (pref.isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SmsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
        }
```

Comment: The thing is you are skipping the activity based on sharedpreference value

Comment: Just don't copy code from other place. Give the detail solution to the problem

Comment: @AjayShrestha you wanted one time login screen so this is it now you could change it according to your code. TY

Comment: @AjayShrestha I have a splash screen too. I am not doing anything in splash screen relative to shared preference rather doing in onCreate of Login screen which I have skip and show only one time so if you successfully login then set preference value else you don't what is the big deal in it

Comment: @AjayShrestha and lastly I could see employee id as unique case so that user can implement one time login screen. Flow is simple in my case i verify otp and in error=false i am calling createLogin with mobile number entered as parameter then in onCreate i am doing the above last thing see code.

Comment: He is asking for the cause of the crash. You are posting the whole bunch of code which doesn't make any sense. Please try to elaborate what part of his code cause the problem and what is the solution

Comment: @SamH67...i followed rafsan &coDfather..its working fine..and simple..anyway thank you for ur answer..can u tell me what is meant by flagactivity clear top and flagactivity new task?